# What is the method transferring an old Clash of clans on account to new device if the old device can't switch on already due to hardware problem

Tags: clash-of-clans

I can't generate link for transferring my old C.O.C account to the new device. Can I use old C.O.C account to other device such iPad and using the old game centre and Apple ID? Will it transfer my previous Clash of Clans Town to the new device? Is it possible?

Comment: Yes! It's possible. Log in into Google Plus in settings, there is an option to set two accounts which lets you link another device.

Answer (score 1):

From last year, Clash of Clans doesn't support old iOS devices run iOS 6 and below. You can't transfer your Clash of Clans account to a new device by using Game Center. Here is the method:

1. Download iExplore on your computer.
2. Connect your old iOS device to your computer, browse to /private/var/mobile/Containers folder then copy the Clash of Clans folder to somewhere in your computer.
3. Connect the new device then copy that folder to /private/var/mobile/Containers (iOS7) or /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application (iOS8).
4. Login with your related Game Center ID.
5. It will ask you if you want to play that Clash of Clans account or not.
6. Enjoy!

Source: http://cocland.com/tutorials/transfer-clash-of-clans-from-old-ios-devices